# combining 2 select statements with different number of columns, where 1st statement is already using JOIN

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to combine 2 select statements with different number of columns.

The 1st statement is this:

```
SELECT s.id, s.date_sent, m.sam_subject, m.sam_msg_id, (SELECT
COUNT(id) FROM tbl_something WHERE schedule_id = s.id) AS
total_recipients FROM tbl_something2 AS s INNER JOIN
tbl_something3 AS m ON s.message_id = m.sam_msg_id ORDER BY
s.date_sent DESC
```

The 2nd statement:

```
SELECT * FROM sms_something4 WHERE status = '0' ORDER BY id DESC
```

the table output for the 1st statement:

```
id date_sent sam_subject sam_msg_id total_recipients

1 1372880628 e-Newsletter 2 2
```

output for 2nd:

```
id | subject | sent | failed | date_sent | data_sent | data_failed | message | sam_uid from | select_members | status | from_no
11 | test    |  2   |  0     |  1372881670 | 639176286411,639224588324 | | | | |                             | 0      | 0
```

any suggestions on how would i be able to combine these two statements?

my target output is

```
id | subject | sent | failed | date_sent | sam_subject | total_recipients | date_sent for email
```

`sam_msg_id` can be ignored.

Thank you.

Comment: i think you answer your own question. join the first statement to 2nd one with subject = sam_subject, date_sent=date_sent, total_Recipients+sent+failed.

Comment: can i still join that even though my 1st statement already has join? i dont really use join that much so i'm not familiar with its limitations

Comment: yes you can still join them.. your first and second statement will consider subquery.. here is link just  read for more info. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html

Comment: @AJP would you be able to help me formulate the query? i'm not really that well verse in join. will read the link though. thanks

Comment: read my answer.. hope it helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is basic  that you need to have .. you might have to trouble shoot. add column as you need.

```
SELECT *
FROM (
SELECT s.id, s.date_sent, m.sam_subject, m.sam_msg_id, (SELECT COUNT(id) 
                                                    FROM tbl_something 
                                                    WHERE schedule_id = s.id) AS total_recipients 
FROM tbl_something2 AS s 
INNER JOIN tbl_something3 AS m 
    ON s.message_id = m.sam_msg_id 
) as tbl
INNER JOIN (SELECT * FROM sms_something4 WHERE status = '0') as tbl2
    ON tbl2.subject = tbl.sam_subject
    and tbl.date_sent=tbl2.date_sent
    and tbl.total_Recipients = tbl2.sent+ tbl2.failed
ORDER BY tbl.date_sent DESC
```

Comment: edited the question since tbl2.subject = tbl1.sam_subject
    and tbl.date_sent=tbl2.date_sent
    and tbl.total_Recipients = tbl2.sent+ tbl2.failed is not really needed. thank you

Comment: u are using that to join.. you dont have to output that.. not sure i understand your edit.

Comment: i removed the subject = sam_subject to avoid confusion that i need them to be equal. since my ideal output is also stated above. tried you query but nothing was returned. do you think you can explain the above query to me a bit. thank you :)

Comment: you said merge 2 statement. so by doing inner join it will give you result where subject = sam_subject and date_sent=datesent and totalrecipients = sent+failed. it didn't return anything because it didn't find match. what you need to do is find the join condition that you want to merge with. i meant something that is common on both result and join with that.

Comment: is it possible to join them without anything in common between the two tables?

Comment: yeah i get it now, wonder if i could do something to avoid adding new field for comparison.

Comment: changed tbl2.subject = tbl.sam_subject
    and tbl.date_sent=tbl2.date_sent
    and tbl.total_Recipients = tbl2.sent+ tbl2.failed
ORDER BY tbl.date_sent DESC with ON tbl2.id = tbl.id. also made it so that both has same id but still no result

Answer (score 1):

As AJP said you can just do this:

```
SELECT s.id, a.subject,a.sent, s.date_sent, m.sam_subject,  
(SELECT COUNT(id) FROM tbl_something WHERE schedule_id = s.id) AS total_recipients 
FROM tbl_something2 AS s 
INNER JOIN tbl_something3 AS m ON s.message_id = m.sam_msg_id 
INNER JOIN
(
SELECT * FROM sms_something4 WHERE status = '0' ORDER BY id DESC
) a on a.subject = m.sam_subject and a.date_sent = s.date_sent
ORDER BY
s.date_sent DESC
```